# Create Condition for selection field in odoo 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8

I have a problem when i was try to create a condition for selection field. I not have idea how to create condition for selection field. So, here my code :

```
_columns = {
    'choose': fields.selection((
            ('first','First'),
            ('second', 'Second'),
    ))
}
```

As all of you know, after i selected the choice, i want to make a condition using "if else". If using basic python,i understand what i have to do. But in odoo, I still confuse about it. Should i build a method or what, i noy have idea.

Answer (score 0):

**If You are working with the same object (model) :**

```
for line in self:
    if line.choose == 'first' :
        print 'You choose the first choice'
    elif line.choose == 'second':
        print 'You choose the second choice'
```

**If You are working on separate object (model):**

```
sale_id=self.search([('name','=','SO102')]).ids
for line in self.browse(sale_id):
    if line.choose == 'first' :
        print 'You choose the first choice'
    elif line.choose == 'second':
        print 'You choose the second choice'
```

Add this logic under your calcuation method and use it

Comment: Is there doesn't need a  function method ?

Comment: Yes sure because without function what you have do in odoo ?

Comment: I was try it, not error but not give me what i want.

```_columns = {
  'active_ids' : fields.char(string='Active IDS'),
  'choose': fields.selection((
    ('by space','By Space'),
    ('by coma', 'By Coma'),
  ))
 }

 def _get_choose(self, cr, uid, ids, choose, context=None):
  if choose == 'by space':
   print "::::::::::::::::::"
   print "NICE"
   print "::::::::::::::::::"
  else:
   print "::::::::::::::::::"
   print "GOOD"
   print "::::::::::::::::::"```

Comment: My code is workable in odoo-8 and its later version also comes under new api only use the method with @api.multi decorator method and implement in your business logic

Comment: if you not yet solved then send me you module on dasadiya.chaitanya@gmail.com